# How to remove hour, minutes and seconds from a date

Tags: c#

I've two types of dates, one in `DateTime` format and another in `string` format, both dates having the following format:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH: mm: ss
```

I want to delete `HH: mm: ss` because I need to compare these dates in a loop to iterate through a database. The problem's that one of these dates is returned by a `CalendarSelectionDate` event, and the hour, minutes and seconds are even set to 0. Anyone have the best way to do this?

**UPDATE:**

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(reader["data"].ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                      DateTimeStyles.None, out dt)){...}
```

The code behavior return an invalid date, in particular if I've 12/05/15 ... the code will return 1/01/0001

Comment: [DateTime.Date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbed0aaa(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: If the `TryParseExact` fails it will return `false` and set your `out` variable `dt` to the default for `DateTime` which is 01-01-0001.  That means your string does not match the format you are using.  Can you show the actual data you are trying to parse?

Comment: Of course, `TryParseExact("12/05/15", "yyyy-MM-dd")` will fail. You have to handle the case when `TryParseExact` returns false (maybe to parse differently ?)

Comment: Sure, this is the date format: 2015-08-23 17:00:00

Comment: @HaroldFinch Using `DateTime.TryParseExact("2015-08-23 17:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                      DateTimeStyles.None, out dt)` works fine for me.

Comment: Have you looked at the third example in my answer ?

Comment: @HaroldFinch You have to understand that `DateTime.Date` will still have a time component, but it will be set to 00:00:00.  If you call `DateTime.Date` on the other `DateTime` you are comparing to then the times will be the same and you'll only be comparing the date parts.

Comment: Maybe you could expand on the comparison you are doing.  Is it with another `DateTime` object, or are you comparing with a `VarChar` value in a DB?

Comment: I've found the bug!! Were the slash "/" and in my string I've passed "-" now working good!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to compare `DateTime` objects without the hour, you can use the `Date` property:

```
if (myDbDate.Date != myUserDate.Date) { }
```

You can also cast the date to a string using ToString(), but be aware that dates are a [notoriously very hard thing to deal with](http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time) when they are strings:

```
if (myDbDate.ToShortDateString() != myUserDate) { }
```

or if you are very sure of your format, you can use a custom date format:

```
if (myDbDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") != myUserDate) { }
```

### Update

Automatically parsing the string to a date (with `DateTime.Parse` or `TryParse`) has often resulted, in my own and personal experience, in very random results. You never seem to know which format .Net will decide on using (`dd/MM` or `MM/dd` ?).

Using `ParseExact` or `TryParseExact` solves this problem, and allows to work on the date further (add days, for instance). But for a simple comparison as in the initial question, since you're "locking" the date format in the code, it doesn't change much (maybe performance-wise, I don't know), and it's much more simple to cast the date to a string than the other way.

That being said, I went on the assumption that the comparison was "is different". If the comparison is "is later/earlier than", casting to a date would indeed be the right solution.

Comment: see my second and third examples

Comment: In general, dates shouldn't be converted to string for comparisons or other operations - the string conversion is (relatively) expensive and the date / time classes in .Net have most functionality needed to deal with dates.

Comment: @HaroldFinch If your second date is a `string` then use `DateTime.TryParse` to get away from the string. You should only keep dates in strings when absolutely necessary.

Comment: @xxbbcc: you're right, but casting a string to a DateTime is pretty hazardous, too. There is never a good solution with dates :/ That being said, juharr's answer uses the parsing method ;)

Comment: I've already use TryParse but the date returned is invalid, check my update post.

Comment: @cosmo0 parsing the `string` to a `DateTime` will let you know if the `string` is in a valid format.  If you format the `DateTime` to a `string` for comparison you have no idea if the `string` you are comparing to is in a valid format.

Comment: In my experience, parsing a date, especially with TryParse, results in completely random data. You never know which part of the date string will result in the month or day. It's much better to use ParseExact (and TryParseExact), but then, since you're "fixing" the format, there is no great difference with casting the date to a string, which is much easier to write.

Comment: Anyway .Date return also the hour, minute and second, so my problem isn't solved.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to understand that `DateTime` does not have a format.  It only contains information that describes a specific point in time.  Formats apply to the string representations of a `DateTime`.  For what you want you can use `DateTime.Date` which will return a new `DateTime` with the same year, month, and day values, but with the time set to 12 AM.  That along with `DateTime.ParseExact` will allow you to parse the `string` to a `DateTime` then compare just the `Date` part.

```
var someDate = DateTime.ParseExact(stringValue, "yyyy-MM-dd HH: mm: ss");
if(someDate.Date != otherDate.Date)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the *base* date of any `DateTime`, simply use the `Date` property.

```
DateTime.Now.Date
```